# Match a custom CRS to existing (proj4 database) ones in QGIS 3

Tags: python, coordinate-system, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am reading `SPS files` ([see format definition here](https://seg.org/Portals/0/SEG/News%20and%20Resources/.../seg_sps_rev2.1.pdf)) from which I gather `CRS` information.
Unfortunately, there is no `ESPG` reference available nor is there any standard naming scheme for `Ellipsoids` so it is easy to get confused and even a well-known `CRS` may be better off built manually.

The `ellipsoidAcronym()` method is not capable of recognizing an existing `Ellipsoid` if I define my `Projection` with `+a` and `+rf` instead of using the `+ellps`. Similarly, the `findMatchingProj()` is failing.
In the following example, using `def_wo_name`, the `Projection` is not recognized (it is actually `EPSG:30732`) and I end up creating a useless custom `CRS` and cluttering my local database.

```
def_wo_name = '+proj=utm +zone=32 +a=6378249.145 +rf=293.4663 +towgs84=-209.3622,-87.8162,404.6198,0.0046,3.4784,0.5805,-1.4547 +units=m +no_defs'
#def_w_name = '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=clrk80 +towgs84=-209.3622,-87.8162,404.6198,0.0046,3.4784,0.5805,-1.4547 +units=m +no_defs'
match = crs.findMatchingProj()
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromProj4(def_wo_name)
print(crs.ellipsoidAcronym())
print(match)
```

The above code output is just the `proj4 string`, an empty string (no `Ellipsoid` match) and `0` (no `Projection` match)

Is there any method that would allow a better (actual) matching or do I have to check my `+a` and `+rf` against all `Ellipsoids` in my database and match manually ?